# 32-bit and 64-bit versions of MSXML 4.0 SP3

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, msxml

In order to support an in-house developed application, the developer is asking for an installation of both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of MSXML 4.0 SP3.  After installing onto Windows Server 2012, the dll's reside in c:\windows\SysWOW64.  I understand that WOW refers to Windows (32-bit) on Windows 64-bit.  In other words, 32-bit apps refer to the directory for dll's needed to run.

I've done extensive searching but have found no indications of a native 64-bit version of MSXML4.  Can anyone point me to the installer on Microsoft's website?

Comment: It does not exist. MSXML 6.0 has a x64 installer you should be using that instead. MSXML 4.0 was released in 2009 to support Windows Vista and WS2008